# Refresh php page in Firefox, strange behavior

Tags: php, firefox, refresh

I have php function, wich prints text and also inserts some data in database, someting like this

```
function bla () {
    echo "bla";

    // here simple SQL for insert into table
}
```

I noticed very strange behavior which happens only in firefox browser.

If just refresh page (F5), php's function doesn't inserts data in database, only prints data, if change printable text, it prints new modified text, but database insert also not happens.

Then, If select url in firefox address bar, and then push F5, php function works fully, means database inserts and printing, both happened.

This just happens only in firefox, in other browsers works as expected, every refreshing page and php's function works fully.

I know this sounds very strange, but it really happens, I test this on localhost.

Firstly, I think this is cache, but as I said already, function prints any modified data at every refreshing, only SQL query not running, SQL insert runs only, If I select firefox  address bar and then refresh page ?!

I don't use any `js` or `cookie` in this case, this is plain php/postgresql and firefox deal.

Any experience with something like this ?

Comment: Chuck on error reporting at the top of your script just for good measure - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-`);` and let us know if anything pops up during testing

Comment: I have error reporting on, there is no any error in php

Comment: Interesting, and what does the insert do exactly? Are there any external factors it relies on?

Comment: Most likely the insert is hitting a Primary Key Violation and the 2nd refresh won't add.  Can't really tell without the sql code

Comment: Bit it works any other browser, without any error, there is no database issue at all, something is wrong with my firefox, but don't understood what exactly